# Silverlight requirements

Tags: silverlight

I am new to silverlight and want to learn silverlight. I have installed Visual Studio 2010 in windows 7 of 64 bits and SQL Server 2008. what are the tools needed or updates for silverlight developer. Would you plz tell me the good sources for learning silverlight. Is ASP.NET MVC 3 of C Sharp knowledge is useful for Silverlight

Comment: Are you aware Microsoft will no longer encourage Silverlight for the desktop? http://goo.gl/QGNvM

Comment: Great Information........This article really discourage me to learn Silverlight. confused

Comment: Learning XAML and Silverlight is still a great skill set to have. XAML will be used in Windows 8 with RT. There has been a lot of articles about the demise of Silverlight and the rise of HTML5 (it all depends on your customers' needs), but I think that it is a good thing to learn. You need C# or VB (it's great to write in managed code, not just Javascript) and you'll also need to know about WCF for data access. see http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/09/build-2011-what-is-winrt-and-i.php for one alt thought

Comment: The articles is confusing having different user different views and opinion claiming this and that language is good. Its totally nightmare to keep track with technology changes. In future, cloud computing trend will prevail so, I want to learn silverlight but many of people has been posting article about demise of Silverlight. I think when I will learning silverlight near by future it would be obsolete and its all useless.... its really amusing to say that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place to start - http://www.silverlight.net/

Follow the steps downwards.

Comment: Is there any other good place to learn silverlight